# API, Sails.js How to send multiples of sms to many number?

Tags: javascript, api, sails.js

I'm trying to send a single messages to multiples number at a time to alarm the admins when user do something in the website but when I send it's only send to the admin2.

```
request.post({
            form: { method: 'send',
                    username: 'max13',
                    password: '****',
                    from: '0000',
                    to:  admin1,
                    message: 'user '+ user_name +' has sent a job'
                                },
                    url: 'http://www.thsms.com/api/rest',

            form: {method: 'send',
                    username: 'max13',
                    password: '****',
                    from: '0000',
                    to:  admin2,
                    message: 'user '+ user_name +' has sent a job'},

                    url: 'http://www.thsms.com/api/rest',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use callback/promise for it. So, that when the sms get sent to admin1 then only it move to admin2.

What happening now is that it's not waiting for api response and moved to another api that why only one admin is getting the sms.

Try this:

```
.then(function(){
    return //your sms api code for admin1  
  })
.then(function(){
    return //your sms api code for admin2  
  })
.fail(function(){
     log error if any of above then block get failed
  })
```

Comment: can you make an example for me?